# Sorting one array from another's one date

Tags: c#

I have Visual Studio 2019. The project is a .Net Windows Form on C# on .Net Framework 4.8.

I have got two arrays.

The first one contains a random number of string values (since they come on a string[]), for example:

```
AB5XHBC1
NMAK72B8
WB5XHBC1
KCZUH528
NZ9YHF3D
PFKR6WNA
```

The second one will always have the same length of the first one, but their values are date-strings, and it could be some string.empty or repeated values in some cases:

```
06/10/2020
08/05/2018

01/12/2020
01/01/2009
01/12/2020
```

What I need to do is sort the first array based on the second one dates. I tried the Array.Sort method but it does not give me the expected result. I'm not really sure if I have used it wrong.

The "null" values must be the firsts, then the newer date (on the top) to the older date (on the bottom), so the resulting array of this example would have to be sort like this (from 0 to 5 position):

```
WB5XHBC1
KCZUH528
PFKR6WNA
NMAK72B8
AB5XHBC1
NZ9YHF3D
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the same amount of data in both of them just make a tuple list and then sort that with Linq.

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. The *strings* in that list can't be ordered in chronological order. You'd have to use the ISO8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD), or store DateTime values

Comment: It's impossible to guess what that localized format is - MM/DD or DD/MM? You can use `DateTime.Parse` to convert the strings to dates, but you need to know what format was used

Comment: @MathewHD sorry but I haven't any knowledge on linq, I am old-school developer. If you could bring me a sample code of it, I could try it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The date format is the default one of my country: DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Possibly some useful examples here? You can use  a Comparer that converts your date strings  to  Date objects then compares them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer?view=netframework-4.8 It's a little tricky to program.

Comment: @operamaxi You need to first format the string to real datetime values like panagiotis said and finding a result with "Linq sort list" will result in more than enugh results.

Comment: @operamaxi are you sure that's the locale of the machine that's going to run your code? Developers often set their locale to `en-US` to avoid localization quirks. Use DateTime objects instead of strings.

Comment: Your expected results are surely wrong? The second oldest is not second from the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement a comparer for your dates (which should implement `IComparer<string>`) and then use [`Array.Sort(keys, values, comparer)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Sort__2___0_____1___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___0__) like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string[] data = 
            {
                "AB5XHBC1",
                "NMAK72B8",
                "WB5XHBC1",
                "KCZUH528",
                "NZ9YHF3D",
                "PFKR6WNA"
            };

            string[] dates =
            {
                "06/10/2020",
                "08/05/2018",
                "",
                "01/12/2020",
                "01/01/2009",
                "01/12/2020"
            };

            Array.Sort(dates, data, new CompareDates());

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", data));
        }
    }

    public sealed class CompareDates: IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            var xd = DateTime.TryParse(x, out DateTime d1) ? d1 : DateTime.MaxValue;
            var yd = DateTime.TryParse(y, out DateTime d2) ? d2 : DateTime.MaxValue;

            return yd.CompareTo(xd);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this gives the output as:

```
WB5XHBC1
KCZUH528
PFKR6WNA
AB5XHBC1
NMAK72B8
NZ9YHF3D
```

I believe this is because your expected results have an error. The second-oldest date is "08/05/2018", which corresponds to the string "NMAK72B8". Therefore, according to your specification, "NMAK72B8" should be second from the end - but in your expected results, "AB5XHBC1" is second from the end.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mOdz3o) (.Net Fiddle).

One thing to watch out for is the date parsing. The code above parses the dates in the current locale, which is assumed to be UK (for the dd/mm/yyyy date format). If you want to parse other date formats, you'll have to change the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Don't mind about the "expected result", I wrote it with fake data. In my real environment, your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can store these in a `List` of `Tuple<string, DateTime>`. I've hardcoded the values in the example below - as other commenters have said, you need to properly parse the date strings into proper `DateTime` objects, etc. I leave that exercise to you.

```
var list = new List<(string RandomString, DateTime Date)>
{
    ("AB5XHBC1", DateTime.Parse("06/10/2020")),
    ("NMAK72B8", DateTime.Parse("08/05/2018")),
    ("WB5XHBC1", DateTime.MaxValue), // simulating null, see below
    ("KCZUH528", DateTime.Parse("01/12/2020")),
    ("NZ9YHF3D", DateTime.Parse("01/01/2009")),
    ("PFKR6WNA", DateTime.Parse("01/12/2020")),
};

var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
```

For the case of the `null` dates appearing first, you can check if the particular date string is `null`. If it is, assign `DateTime.MaxValue` as a value, otherwise parse it and use the actual value. The logic of this check could resemble the one below:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(whateverStringDate) ? DateTime.MaxValue : DateTime.Parse(whateverStringDate);
```

This should point you in the right direction, [@Matthew Watson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262910/4302070) would be a much more elegant and complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!